# Removing (deleting) a table row from an HTML table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help.

I am attempting to selectively remove the table row at the click of button, but it does not seem that the code is working as it should, nothing is happening.

Perhaps a fresh set of eyes might be the cure for this one!

I am jQuery friendly!

The code in question:

```
$('#remove_row').click(function() {

    var $row = $tbody.find('.highlight')

    $("#data tr").eq($row).remove();

});
```

Here is the markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<style type="text/css">

.highlight {

    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);

}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

var rowCount = $('#data >tbody >tr').length;
$("#maxrows").val(rowCount);

    var $tbody = $("#data tbody").on('click', 'tr', function() {
            highlight($(this));
    });


    $('#goto_first').click(function() {
        var $first = $tbody.find('tr').first();
            highlight($first);
    });

    $('#goto_prev').click(function() {
        var $prev = $tbody.find('.highlight').prev();
            highlight($prev);
    });


    $('#goto_next').click(function() {
        var $next = $tbody.find('.highlight').next();
            highlight($next);
    });

    $('#goto_last').click(function() {
        var $last = $tbody.find('tr').last();
            highlight($last);
    });

    $('#goto_row').click(function() {

        var $row = prompt("Enter row number")

        highlight($("#data tr").eq($row));

    });

    $('#remove_row').click(function() {

        var $row = $tbody.find('.highlight')

        $("#data tr").eq($row).remove();

    });


    function highlight($row) {
            if ($row.length) {
                $tbody.children().removeClass("highlight");
                $row.addClass('highlight');
                $("#rownum").val($row[0].rowIndex);
            }
    }

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>header2</th>
            <th>header3</th>
            <th>header4</th>
            <th>header5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Row Number:
<br>
<input type="text" id="rownum" readonly><br>
of
<br>
<input type="text" id="maxrows" readonly>
<br>
<input type="button" id="goto_first" value="first">
<input type="button" id="goto_prev" value="prev">
<input type="button" id="goto_next" value="next">
<input type="button" id="goto_last" value="last">
<input type="button" id="goto_row" value="goto row">
<input type="button" id="remove_row" value="remove row">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$row` is already a reference to the row you want to remove. Change:

```
$("#data tr").eq($row).remove();
```

to:

```
$row.remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dvFrd/)**

Comment: You beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change remove function to:

```
$('#remove_row').click(function() {

    $tbody.find('.highlight').remove();

});
```